# Closetmaid Shelving

Tags: storage, shelves

So I bought some used closetmaid shelves and for whatever reason they did not have all the track system pieces. Basically just got the shelves.

My question is, can I just use regular brackets to somehow attach the wire shelves like you would boards of wood? Or am I crazy?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: You should be able to find Closet Maid hardware (wall clips, brackets, etc) in any box box store.

Answer (score 0):

Most "normal" shelving is wood and securing will almost certainly not be the same because you can't just run a screw through the bracket into the shelf to secure it.

That said, there is no reason you can't use the shelves with most standard brackets (albeit with some creative securing that varies based on the brackets), but the rail and bracket system they use is quite convenient for adjusting height and I would recommend buying rails and brackets unless you hate the look.